# HTTPS, how to use it in according to Google Policy

Tags: java, android, https, google-play

I received an email from Google saying

```
Apps handling personal or sensitive user data (including personally identifiable information, financial and payment information, authentication information, phonebook or contact data, microphone and camera sensor data, and sensitive device data) must handle the user data securely, including transmitting it using modern cryptography (for example, over HTTPS)
```

But in my app I already use HTTPS with the following function:

```
public boolean connectAndSendToServer( JSONArray args )
{
    String rispostaServer       =   "";
    try
    {
        HttpClient httpclient   =   new DefaultHttpClient();
        httpclient.getParams().setParameter("http.protocol.version", HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        httpclient.getParams().setParameter("http.protocol.content-charset", "UTF-8");
        HttpPost httppost       =   new HttpPost( "https://....org/Framework/Web/index.php" );

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs      =   new ArrayList<NameValuePair>( 1 );

        for ( int x = 0; x < args.length(); x++ )
        {
            JSONObject jsonTemp     =   (JSONObject) args.get( x );
            nameValuePairs.add( new BasicNameValuePair( jsonTemp.get( "chiave" ).toString() , ( ( jsonTemp.get( "valore" ) == null ) ? "null" : jsonTemp.get( "valore" ).toString() ) ) );
        }

        httppost.setEntity( new UrlEncodedFormEntity( nameValuePairs, "UTF-8" ) );

        // Esegue la Richiesta HTTP Post
        HttpResponse response   =   httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity       =   response.getEntity();

        // Crea un oggetto JSON dalla risposta fornita dalla richiesta
        rispostaServer  =   EntityUtils.toString( entity );

        try
        {
            jsonObjectServerResponse    =   new JSONArray( rispostaServer );
        }
        catch ( Exception e )
        {
            jsonObjectServerResponse    =   new JSONArray().put( new JSONObject( rispostaServer ) );
        }

        return true;
    }
    catch( Exception eE )
    {
        eE.printStackTrace();
    }

    return false;
}
```

So I am worried about another UI concern: I ask the confirm to the license in the last fragment of my viewpager in order to process the registration, but previously in the precedent fragments I collect user data in order to send them in case the user approves the license...could it be that the other reason?